# How to Set Up Continent-Based Table Rates in Magento 2.4.6 Without Custom Development?

Tags: shipping, table-rates

I'm trying to set up table rates for shipping based on continents in Magento 2.4.6. The goal is to have different shipping rates for different weight ranges, but categorized by continent instead of individual countries. I would like to find a way to do this without having to build a whole custom module.

I've tried creating a CSV file with the following example data:

the * is not showing in-between the commas below, they are there though.

EU,*,*,0,35
EU,*,*,29,35
EU,*,*,30,55
EU,*,*,59,55
EU,*,*,60,75
EU,*,*,89,75
EU,*,*,90,95
EU,*,*,120,95

However, Magento doesn't seem to recognize the 'EU' continent code and throws errors when I attempt to import it. The errors are as follows:

> The "EU" country in row number "26" is incorrect. Verify the country and try again.

...
Is there a workaround for this issue that doesn't involve listing each country in the continent individually or building a custom module? I want to save time and effort on this if possible. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, Magento 2 out of the box does not support continent management at all, the highest level that can be managed is country. So you can't achieve such work without custom development. I suggest manually populating your table rates CSV file with proper data. Cheers!